# Add lines from bubble to popup template on a datamap

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have a custom bubble map on India geographical region which is done using data maps

There is html file and when i open it in browser i will get this result[image: Image 1]

Code is mentioned below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/Anujarya300/bubble_maps/master/data/geography-data/datamaps.none.js"></script>
<div id="india" style="height: 600px; width: 900px;"></div>
<script>
    var bubble_map = new Datamap({
        element: document.getElementById('india'),
        scope: 'india',
        geographyConfig: {
            popupOnHover: true,
            highlightOnHover: true,
            borderColor: '#444',
            borderWidth: 0.5,
            dataUrl: 'https://rawgit.com/Anujarya300/bubble_maps/master/data/geography-data/india.topo.json'
            //dataJson: topoJsonData
        },
        fills: {
            'MAJOR': '#306596',
            'MEDIUM': '#0fa0fa',
            'MINOR': '#bada55',
            defaultFill: '#dddddd'
        },
        data: {
            'JH': { fillKey: 'MINOR' },
            'MH': { fillKey: 'MINOR' }
        },
        setProjection: function (element) {
            var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
                .center([78.9629, 23.5937]) // always in [East Latitude, North Longitude]
                .scale(1000);
            var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);
            return { path: path, projection: projection };
        }
    });

    let bubbles = [
        {
            centered: "MH",
            fillKey: "MAJOR",
            radius: 7,
            state: "Maharastra"
        },
        {
            centered: "AP",
            fillKey: "MAJOR",
            radius: 7,
            state: "Andhra Pradesh"
        },
        {
            centered: "TN",
            fillKey: "MAJOR",
            radius: 7,
            state: "Tamil Nadu"
        },
        {
            centered: "WB",
            fillKey: "MEDIUM",
            radius: 7,
            state: "West Bengal"
        },
        {
            centered: "MP",
            fillKey: "MEDIUM",
            radius: 7,
            state: "Madhya Pradesh"
        },
        {
            centered: "UP",
            fillKey: "MINOR",
            radius: 7,
            state: "Uttar Pradesh"
        },
        {
            centered: "RJ",
            fillKey: "MINOR",
            radius: 7,
            state: "Rajasthan"
        }

    ]

    let data = {

    };
    // // ISO ID code for city or <state></state>
    setTimeout(() => { // only start drawing bubbles on the map when map has rendered completely.
        bubble_map.bubbles(bubbles, {
            popupTemplate: function (geo, data) {
                return `<div class="hoverinfo">city: ${data.state}, Slums: ${data.radius}%</div>`;
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
 </script>
 </body>

</html>
```

Now i need a slight modification to the UI ,

I need to draw  lines from the bubble to the pop up template which some what looks like this below image .
[image: Image 2]

So how i can modify the code? So that when i hover on each and every bubble i need a line from the bubble to a popup template.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added Styles for Tooltip indicator.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/Anujarya300/bubble_maps/master/data/geography-data/datamaps.none.js"></script>
    <!-- Style for tooltip indicator starts-->
    <style>
        hr {
            width: 41%;
            height: 2px;
            background-color: #000;
            border: none;
            margin-top: -25px;
            margin-bottom: 27px;
            margin-left: 14px;
        }

        .vl {
            border-left: 2px solid #000;
            height: 30px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -1px;
            top: -25px;
        }
    </style>
     <!-- Style for tooltip indicator end-->
    <div id="india" style="height: 600px; width: 900px;"></div>
    <script>
    var bubble_map = new Datamap({
        element: document.getElementById('india'),
        scope: 'india',
        geographyConfig: {
            popupOnHover: true,
            highlightOnHover: true,
            borderColor: '#444',
            borderWidth: 0.5,
            dataUrl: 'https://rawgit.com/Anujarya300/bubble_maps/master/data/geography-data/india.topo.json'
            //dataJson: topoJsonData
        },
        fills: {
            'MAJOR': '#306596',
            'MEDIUM': '#0fa0fa',
            'MINOR': '#bada55',
            defaultFill: '#dddddd'
        },
        data: {
            'JH': { fillKey: 'MINOR' },
            'MH': { fillKey: 'MINOR' }
        },
        setProjection: function (element) {
            var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
                .center([78.9629, 23.5937]) // always in [East Latitude, North Longitude]
                .scale(1000);
            var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);
            return { path: path, projection: projection };
        }
    });

    let bubbles = [
        {
            centered: "MH",
            fillKey: "MAJOR",
            radius: 7,
            state: "Maharastra"
        },
        {
            centered: "AP",
            fillKey: "MAJOR",
            radius: 7,
            state: "Andhra Pradesh"
        },
        {
            centered: "TN",
            fillKey: "MAJOR",
            radius: 7,
            state: "Tamil Nadu"
        },
        {
            centered: "WB",
            fillKey: "MEDIUM",
            radius: 7,
            state: "West Bengal"
        },
        {
            centered: "MP",
            fillKey: "MEDIUM",
            radius: 7,
            state: "Madhya Pradesh"
        },
        {
            centered: "UP",
            fillKey: "MINOR",
            radius: 7,
            state: "Uttar Pradesh"
        },
        {
            centered: "RJ",
            fillKey: "MINOR",
            radius: 7,
            state: "Rajasthan"
        }

    ]

    let data = {

    };
    // // ISO ID code for city or <state></state>
    setTimeout(() => { // only start drawing bubbles on the map when map has rendered completely.
        bubble_map.bubbles(bubbles, {
            popupTemplate: function (geo, data) {
                // Code for tooltip indicator 
                return `
                <hr>
                <div class="vl"></div>
                <div class="hoverinfo">city: ${data.state}, Slums: ${data.radius}%</div>
                `;
            }
        });

    }, 1000);
 </script>
</body>

</html>
```